# Website doesn't recognize GET even though manual URL works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest-states

I have a custom website which checks on `document.ready` if there is a parameter called 'temp' in the URL-line. If so, I call a PHP-function on my server which stores the value in a database. Now the strange thing for me is that if  manually type this:

`http://mywebsite.org/?temp=7`

in my browser, everything works fine. But if I use this website to test GET:

http://requestmaker.com/

my website does nothing.

This is my jQuery code, which checks the existence of a parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var data = gup('temp', location.href);
      if (data != undefined) {
        $.ajax({
          data: {
            action: 'insertTemp',
            value: data
          },
          type: "GET",
          url: "SQL.php",
          success: function(data) {
            //alert("Data Saved " + data);
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
      }
```

Do you think that the `document.ready` could be a problem because it is not checked at automated HTML-requests?

Edit:

Gup is a function I copied from the internet, it just filters for the parameter in the URL:

```
function gup(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)", "i"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

It is declared outside the `document.ready()` clause.

This is the response code I get from `requestmaker.com`:

http://pastebin.com/WL2CQP4v

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's console for errors? Where are you defining `gup()`?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment,
no, my browser does not throw anny erros, gup is just a function i copied from the internet which filters the url for parameters:
`function gup(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)", "i"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }`

Comment: What about the request / response in the network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: This is the request/response if i use this command:
`www.mywebsite.org/temp=2`
http://pastebin.com/ZMG58Dc5

Comment: Those are the headers, what about the actual data?

Comment: This is in the `Query String Parameters` field, it contains the data sent to the PHP-Function:
`action:insertTemp
value:2`

Comment: No response from the PHP?

Comment: Okay, this is the `echo` my PHP-function sends if the database `INSERT` was sucessfully:
`Entered value successfully` (under the `Response` tab). So i guess that works fine. But i don't understand what's the difference between my manual insert and the `HTML GET`?

Comment: So, the AJAX is working. `console.log(data)` in your success function.

Comment: `Entered value successfully` as well.

Comment: Now you need to check your web server's error logs. The AJAX is fine, but something is hinky with your PHP script. Maybe post your PHP code here too.

Comment: Why should there be an error with my PHP-script? It returns the `echo` it should? Hm, i have to find out first how i can read my web server's error logs...

Comment: Because the AJAX works, yet nothing gets inserted to your database which is the responsibility of your PHP code.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry it looks like you missunderstood something. The process and data i just described happens when i insert the URL `manually` in my browser. This is the data if i try to make a html request with requestmaker.com:
http://pastebin.com/WL2CQP4v
`Response Body:` is just the pure HTML/JS from my website.

Comment: If you're making a request with AJAX you can do it as a GET request.

Comment: Is it possible to create ajax requests from a desktop app to a website? If i want to stick with HTML guess i have to send the request directly to the SQL function as @Reto mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

This is because requestmaker.com is only sending the request and showing you the response. Its not really executing the webpage in a web engine/browser.

You didn't write what your end-goal is, but if its for automated testing and like maybe you should check out `travis-ci`, `phantomjs` or similar tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to send data to the webpage and it stores it in a database automatically.
I also tried to send a HTML-GET to my website from a desktop application with the same result that my website didn't store the data and i don't know why. I think `requestmaker` just does the same thing as my desktop app - it sends a html request. Of course that is not executed in a browser because usually it doesn't need a browser to send data via a html request to a website (this would actually take a lot of resources), but it should still work.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is two parts of a website, client-side and server-side. What you're doing (Checking url parameter, sending ajax request) is from client side. But the environments you're testing doesn't execute the client side. 

From what i understand your goal: You should write all the code in client side. 
Make a index.php that reads $_GET['temp'] and redirects to your target (SQL.php).
Ex: `header('Location: /SQL.php?action=insertTemp&value='.$_GET['temp']);`

NB: this is really bad code. You proper user input sanitation in prod.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your embeded ECMA (Javascript) code relies on a browser to be executed. The 'document.ready' wont be fired without a browser..

Comment: Okay...But how can i do it then?